# Find the coordinates of a point equidistant from two given points

Tags: analytic-geometry

The Coordinates of two points are A(-2,6) and B(9,3).  Find the coordinates of the point C on the x-axis such that AC = BC

Comment: Use the distance formula on a point $(c,0)$ ; solve for $c$.

Answer (score 3):

A general approach:

Given two points $A$ and $B$, the line that is perpendicular to the segment $AB$ and goes through its midpoint is *precisely* the set of points that are equidistant from $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Correct, but then you have to find the intersection with the x axis.

Comment: @Hi Ross. That's correct. I think in general this is cleaner than playing with the distance formula.

Comment: Well, using the distance formula seems to require less computation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andres C. that you have to find the equation of the perpendicular bisector of points A and B. And also with what Ross M. says that you must find out where this perpendicular bisector intersects with the x axis by substituting y=0.